# Looking for guidance on when to create new App Service vs adding a function to existing

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using consumption plan functions. 
I can add a new function to an existing App Service or I can create a new App Service. I just realized that I don't have an adequate understanding of in what situations one should add a new App Service. Would appreciate any high-level guidance on that.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the unit of scale for a function is the Function App. So if the runtime determines that one function needs to be scaled, it will scale the Function App and all functions within it.

If your function can run in the consumption plan (finish within 5 minutes) and is logically related to the other functions, then I would probably add it to the current consumption plan.

However, if it needs to run for longer than 5 minutes or it is not related to the other functions, I would separate it to its own plan.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, consumption plan can scale "indefinitely", so there is no real reason to create another App Service, unless you want to logically separate those, or give out specific permissions (as you can't have permissions to functions inside Azure Function) or say, you want some of them to be configured from Git and some not.